# Bug with with 100% height of flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

please see jsbin.
[enter link description here](https://jsbin.com/zohuqugepa/1/edit?html,css,output)

i have some bug with 100% height on flex container. when is too more content, it falls from container

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to create/open

```
<div class="col col2">
```

after

```
<div class="col col1">
</div> place <div class="col col2"> after the ending div of col col1
```

Also replace your css code with this one:

```
html,body{
  height:100%; /*Having 100% stretches your content, try removing height:100%; and see the difference*/
}

.parent{
  padding:10px;
  background:#888;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /*Using flex-wrap:wrap will wrap your second div class to the next line*/
  flex:1 0 auto;
}

.col1{
  background:yellow;
}

.col2{
  background:lightgreen;
}
```